# CodeName One Transitions

Tags: android, codenameone

I'm trying to transition part of a form, ie: when you click on a multiline button, just the content part of the form moves, while the header remains static. I'm not sure how to accomplish this or if it is possible. From what I can tell, you can do the whole form, but not parts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you place a Container within the center of the form you can replace it by using:

```
myContainer.getParent().replace(myContainer, newContainer, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, 500, true);
```